# Something wrong with the "Make a map" tutorial?

Tags: ros, beginner-tutorials, beginner

[image: Rosanswers logo]

When I follow the tutorials at "Make A Map", I execute the command "roslaunch turtlebot_gazebo turtlebot_playground.launch" in a terminal, but serveral errors are resonsed and the turtlebot environment does not appear as expected as the picture show. What happend? How can i fix it? or just this tutorial needs to be updated.

I am working with ROS-Hydro and the Ubuntu 12.04.  The following are executed in a terminal:
$ source /opt/ros/hydro/setup.bash \n
$ export TURTLEBOT_BASE=create \n
$ export TURTLEBOT_STACKS=circles \n
$ export TURTLEBOT_3D_SENSOR=asus_xtion_pro \n
$ roslaunch turtlebot_gazebo turtlebot_playground.launch \n

The Error is as follows:
......
Error [ModelDatabase.cc:408] Unable to download model[model://dumpster/meshes/dumpster.dae]
Error [SystemPaths.cc:371] File or path does not exist[""]
....
....
....
....（Many Warnings and Errors）

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/104451/something-wrong-with-the-%22make-a-map%22-tutorial-??/) by [zhangyong19800721@gmail.com](https://answers.ros.org/users/9121/zhangyong19800721@gmail.com/) on ROS Answers with karma: 21 on 2013-11-24

Post score: 2

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Tirjen](https://answers.ros.org/users/7761/tirjen/) on 2013-11-24**:
Which version of ROS are you using? Can you post the errors?

**Comment by [Neil Traft](https://answers.ros.org/users/17791/neil-traft/) on 2014-05-15**:
Same issue here; models of the cylinder and bookshelf still show up but dumpster, cube_20k, and jersey_barrier are missing or have been moved. Otherwise it works fine.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I can tell you that I have the same error (using ROS Hydro and the same version of Ubuntu), it seems like gazebo is unable to find and download several models that are in this world it tries to launch.

Does the launch file turtlebot_empty_world.launch work?
If it works I suggest you to create your own environment (using boxes, cylinders or also other objects) and use this world for building a map.

---

Originally posted by [Tirjen](https://answers.ros.org/users/7761/tirjen/) with karma: 808 on 2013-11-25

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Update: It works if you manually download the required models onto your computer. I found this information over [here](http://answers.gazebosim.org/question/4399/turtlebot_gazebo-world-not-loading-models/).

> wget http://gazebosim.org/models/dumpster/model.tar.gz
> tar xvf model.tar.gz -C ~/.gazebo/models

And then do the same for whichever model you want from [here](http://gazebosim.org/models/)

I have the same error with 12.04 and Hydro. The empty world option with self-generated objects as mentioned above is a workaround but that also means we cannot use Gazebo's database of models. Hopefully, someone can make a permanent fix for this.

---

Originally posted by [2ROS0](https://answers.ros.org/users/18936/2ros0/) with karma: 1133 on 2014-06-26

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1